# dotdotdot jquery plugin not working for display: inline-block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dotdotdot

```
div {
   width: 50px;
}

span {
   display: inline-block;
}

p {
  max-height: calc(1em + 5px);
}

<div>
   <span>a</span>
   <span><p class="ellipsis">b</p></span>
</div>
```

It seems when ellipsis is applied to the p it calculates the width as if it were the full width of the div, rather than its width - width of a (as they are display: inline)

I can see when I inspect that it calculates the ... as if it were the full width of div. Does anyone know a workaround for this (it works for the normal cases I use it in)?

Comment: in html element you dont have to use dot while giving class. Your p must read like `<p class="ellipsis">b</p>`

Comment: You can not nest `p` into `span`, that is invalid HTML. And you should really provide a testable example, a jsfiddle or something like that.